# Intellij idea требует указания модулей, но я их уже указывал

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Прошу помощи! intellij idea при запуске программы требует указания модулей. сначала я в VM Options указывал путь --module-path="C\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,но он выдал ошибку. потом я указал все, javafx.base javafx.controls javafx.fxml javafx.graphics javafx.media javafx.swing javafx.web и всё равно выдает ошибку. Путь к библиотеке FX указал вроде правильно, C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib т.к. в импорте они перестали подсвечиваться красным. Весь инет перерыл, но конкретно на мой вопрос ответ так и не нашел. В чём моя ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробелы вокруг "=" надо убрать.

Comment: Эникейщик, не помогло(((

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса